# Trying to write python code asking user for the name of the input file, it works but when I enter the input file it says 'input file' is not defined?

Tags: python, user-input

This is my code with lines 4-6 asking for the input file:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

infile = input('Enter input file name:') 
mags = open( infile ,'r')
cluster = input('Enter the name of the cluster:')

vmag=[]
imag=[]

for line in mags:
    column = line.split()
    flag=int(float(column[0]))
    RA=(column[14])
    DEC=(column[15])
    RA = int(float(RA.split(':')[2]))
    DEC = int(float(DEC.split(':')[2]))

    a = input('Enter flag lower range value')
    b = input('Enter flag higher range value')    
    c = input('Enter RA lower range value:')
    d = input('Enter RA higher range value:')
    e = input('Enter DEC lower range value:')
    f = input('Enter DEC higher range value:')

    if flag in range (a,b):
    #if flag == 0:
        if RA in range (c,d):

             if DEC in range (e,f):

                vmag.append(float(column[1]))
                imag.append(float(column[4]))   

vmag = np.array(vmag)
imag = np.array(imag)


plt.scatter(vmag-imag, vmag, lw=0, s=5)
plt.ylim(27, 21)
plt.xlim(-0.5, 3.0)
plt.title('Colour Magnitude Diagram', cluster)
plt.ylabel('F555 mag')
plt.xlabel('F555-F814')
plt.grid(b=True)
plt.savefig(cluster, '.pdf')
plt.show()
```

But when I run it and enter the input file 'ngc185_u3kl01.txt'(which is in the same directory) I get the following error:

```
Enter input file name:ngc185_u3kl01
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-917781cbe168>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Keith/.spyder2/CMD.py', wdir='C:/Users/Keith/.spyder2')

  File "C:\Users\Keith\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Keith/.spyder2/CMD.py", line 5, in <module>
    infile = input('Enter input file name:')

  File "C:\Users\Keith\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.py", line 364, in <lambda>
    input = lambda prompt='': eval(raw_input(prompt))

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'ngc185_u3kl01' is not defined
```

I have checked and double checked the name of the file matches what I type, even copied and pasted the input file name but still no success. I have also tried it with and without '.txt' on the end.

Comment: Because `name 'ngc185_u3kl01' is` surely `not defined`, but `name 'ngc185_u3kl01.txt' is` surely `defined`. I mean to say that you should input the name as `ngc185_u3kl01.txt`

Comment: I get the exact same error regardless of the .txt

Answer (score 1):

On Python 2 you should use `raw_input`, not `input`.
`input` evaluates the result into a number or string, and is considered dangerous and unpythonic, since you must catch the exception if the user inputs something bad, like a unquoted string or just nothing.

`input` is really just archaic and a cliche from the old days. That's why they changed it in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

or you can keep "input" function and use a Python 3.x interpreter.